# What is the name of the element to mimic an article on a web browser in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am developing a wireframe in draw.io but there is a feature I once saw someone used on their browser mockup similar to this:

[image]

I have not been able to locate that element in draw.io, can anyone tell me what the name of this element is on draw.io?

Answer (score 1):

The similar elements can be found under More shapes (bottom left) > GMDL (Material design) e.g Cards etc. or Atlassian or you could use iconGrid and modify it. There are some Wireframe templates that might help you (File > New > Wireframe)

Kind regards,